# MongoDB login with user account

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a administrative user according to the doc:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "siteUserAdmin2",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Then I create a user in Mongodb console:

```
use x
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "xuser",
      pwd: "xuser123",
      roles: ["readWrite"]
    }
)
```

I can log in to the admin user in console like this:

```
mongo --port 27017 -u siteUserAdmin -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

But how do I login the user account?

I tried the username and password it wouldn't let me through. I also don't know what to put in `--authenticationDatabase`. I cannot log in using Mongoose either.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are connecting with user credentials from something like mongoose or other drivers, it is generally preferred to use the [connection string format.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/)

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://siteuserAdmin:password@localhost/admin')
```

And of course connect to the authentication database as mentioned

> If you do not specify a value for --authenticationDatabase, mongo uses the database specified in the connection string.

That would be the case for a connection that needs to perform administrative options. Otherwise then the credentials can be supplied and the connection made to the appropriate database that account has privileges for.

Comment: Silly me, it's because I didn't know better to login to the db I actually want to use! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can log with `xuser` by specifying the database. I created the same user that you have and tried logging in from the console and it works just fine.

```
mongo --username xuser --pasword xuser123 --authenticationDatabase x
```

Once logged in, I also ran the `connectionStatus` command to see the current user:

```
db.runCommand({connectionStatus: 1});

//output
{
        "authInfo" : {
                "authenticatedUsers" : [
                        {
                                "user" : "xuser",
                                "db" : "x"
                        }
                ]
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Oh! It's the authentication db option that I am messing up. Thanks